# Animate a plot of a matrix with python?

Tags: python-2.7, plot

I have written a lot of code with Python, but I am very new to plotting.

I have a list of matrices, and I want to plot all of them (in the sense of a matrix plot, see the figure), and then join all the plots in an animation. Can someone provide a working example of how this is done in Python? I haven't found any in the web.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you have 2D array data probbably this line of code can do what you want

> plt.pcolormesh(2D_data, cmap='inferno')

Also here are some useful links:
[2D data plotting using ccolormap python](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/09/colormaps-matplotlib/)